# What does multicore assembly language look like?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, multicore, smp

Once upon a time, to write x86 assembler, for example, you would have instructions stating "load the EDX register with the value 5", "increment the EDX" register, etc.

With modern CPUs that have 4 cores (or even more), at the machine code level does it just look like there are 4 separate CPUs (i.e. are there just 4 distinct "EDX" registers) ?  If so, when you say "increment the EDX register", what determines which CPU's EDX register is incremented? Is there a "CPU context" or "thread" concept in x86 assembler now?

How does communication/synchronization between the cores work?

If you were writing an operating system, what mechanism is exposed via hardware to allow you to schedule execution on different cores? Is it some special priviledged instruction(s)?

If you were writing an optimizing compiler/bytecode VM for a multicore CPU, what would you need to know specifically about, say, x86 to make it generate code that runs efficiently across all the cores?

What changes have been made to x86 machine code to support multi-core functionality?

Comment: There's a similar (though not identical) question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714905/threads-in-x86-assembler-using-the-gnu-assember-as

Answer (score 195, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but it's an answer to a question that appears in the comments.  Essentially, the question is what support the hardware gives to multi-core operation, the ability to run multiple software threads at truly the same time, without software context-switching between them.  (Sometimes called an [SMP system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing)).

[Nicholas Flynt had it right](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19521/nicholas-flynt), at least regarding x86.  In a multi-core environment (Hyper-threading, multi-core or multi-processor), the *Bootstrap core* (usually hardware-thread (aka logical core) 0 in core 0 in processor 0) starts up fetching code from address `0xfffffff0`.  All the other cores (hardware threads) start up in a special sleep state called *Wait-for-SIPI*.  As part of its initialization, the primary core sends a special inter-processor-interrupt (IPI) over the APIC called a SIPI (Startup IPI) to each core that is in WFS.  The SIPI contains the address from which that core should start fetching code.

This mechanism allows each core to execute code from a different address.  All that's needed is software support for each hardware core to set up its own tables and messaging queues.

The OS uses *those* to do the actual multi-threaded scheduling of software tasks.  (A normal OS only has to bring up other cores once, at bootup, unless you're hot-plugging CPUs, e.g. in a virtual machine.  This is separate from starting or migrating software threads onto those cores.  Each core *is running the kernel*, which spends its time calling a sleep function to wait for an interrupt if there isn't anything else for it to be doing.)

As far as the actual assembly is concerned, as Nicholas wrote, there's no difference between the assemblies for a single threaded or multi threaded application. Each core has its own register set (execution context), so writing:

```
mov edx, 0
```

will only update `EDX` for the *currently running thread*.  There's no way to modify `EDX` on another processor using a single assembly instruction.  You need some sort of system call to ask the OS to tell another thread to run code that will update its own `EDX`.

Comment: Thanks for filling the gap in Nicholas' answer. Have marked yours as the accepted answer now.... gives the specific details I was interested in... although it would be better if there was a single answer that had your information and Nicholas' all combined.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of where the threads come from.  Cores and processors is a hardware thing, but somehow threads must be created in software.  How does the primary thread know where to send the SIPI?  Or does the SIPI itself create a new thread?

Comment: @richremer: It seems like you're confusing HW threads and SW threads.  The HW thread always exists.  Sometimes it's asleep.  The SIPI itself wakes the HW thread and allows it to run SW.  It is up to the OS and BIOS to decide which HW threads run, and which processes and SW threads run on each HW thread.

Comment: Lots of good and concise info here, but this is a big topic - so questions can linger. There are a few examples of complete "bare bones" kernels in the wild that boot from USB drives or "floppy" disks - here's an x86_32 version written in assembler using the old TSS descriptors that can actually run multi-threaded C code (https://github.com/duanev/oz-x86-32-asm-003) but there is no standard library support.  Quite a bit more than you asked for but it can maybe answer some of those lingering questions.

Comment: @richremer: This answer previous used "thread" for both logical core (hardware thread) and for software thread.  You had to already understand that piece of background knowledge to know which it was talking about where.  I've disambiguated it, writing "logical core" or "core" everywhere it was talking about a hardware execution context, and "thread" everywhere it was talking about software threads / processes that an OS can schedule onto the cores of the machine.  (On CPUs with Hyperthreading or other SMT, each physical core has multiple execution contexts, aka logical cores).

Answer (score 138):

### Intel x86 minimal runnable baremetal example

[Runnable bare metal example with all required boilerplate](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/4ada3c2cd03784d53e263ec7eb35722d41d6de7a/smp.S). All major parts are covered below.

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10 QEMU 2.3.0 and Lenovo ThinkPad T400 [real hardware guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/how-to-run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/32483545#32483545).

The [Intel Manual Volume 3 System Programming Guide - 325384-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081259/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) covers SMP in chapters 8, 9 and 10.

Table 8-1. "Broadcast INIT-SIPI-SIPI Sequence and Choice of Timeouts" contains an example that basically just works:

```
MOV ESI, ICR_LOW    ; Load address of ICR low dword into ESI.
MOV EAX, 000C4500H  ; Load ICR encoding for broadcast INIT IPI
                    ; to all APs into EAX.
MOV [ESI], EAX      ; Broadcast INIT IPI to all APs
; 10-millisecond delay loop.
MOV EAX, 000C46XXH  ; Load ICR encoding for broadcast SIPI IP
                    ; to all APs into EAX, where xx is the vector computed in step 10.
MOV [ESI], EAX      ; Broadcast SIPI IPI to all APs
; 200-microsecond delay loop
MOV [ESI], EAX      ; Broadcast second SIPI IPI to all APs
                    ; Waits for the timer interrupt until the timer expires
```

On that code:

1. Most operating systems will make most of those operations impossible from ring 3 (user programs).

   So you need to write your own kernel to play freely with it: a userland Linux program will not work.
2. At first, a single processor runs, called the bootstrap processor (BSP).

   It must wake up the other ones (called Application Processors (AP)) through special interrupts called [Inter Processor Interrupts (IPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-processor_interrupt).

   Those interrupts can be done by programming Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller (APIC) through the Interrupt command register (ICR)

   The format of the ICR is documented at: 10.6 "ISSUING INTERPROCESSOR INTERRUPTS"

   The IPI happens as soon as we write to the ICR.
3. ICR_LOW is defined at 8.4.4 "MP Initialization Example" as:

   ```
   ICR_LOW EQU 0FEE00300H
   ```

   The magic value `0FEE00300` is the memory address of the ICR, as documented at Table 10-1 "Local APIC Register Address Map"
4. The simplest possible method is used in the example: it sets up the ICR to send broadcast IPIs which are delivered to all other processors except the current one.

   But it is also possible, [and recommended by some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368043/895245), to get information about the processors through special data structures setup by the BIOS like [ACPI tables or Intel's MP configuration table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146059/how-can-i-detect-the-number-of-cores-in-x86-assembly) and only wake up the ones you need one by one.
5. `XX` in `000C46XXH` encodes the address of the first instruction that the processor will execute as:

   ```
   CS = XX * 0x100
   IP = 0
   ```

   Remember that [CS multiples addresses by `0x10`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777146/what-is-the-purpose-of-cs-and-ip-registers-in-intel-8086-assembly/33177253#33177253), so the actual memory address of the first instruction is:

   ```
   XX * 0x1000
   ```

   So if for example `XX == 1`, the processor will start at `0x1000`.

   We must then ensure that there is 16-bit real mode code to be run at that memory location, e.g. with:

   ```
   cld
   mov $init_len, %ecx
   mov $init, %esi
   mov 0x1000, %edi
   rep movsb

   .code16
   init:
       xor %ax, %ax
       mov %ax, %ds
       /* Do stuff. */
       hlt
   .equ init_len, . - init
   ```

   Using a linker script is another possibility.
6. The delay loops are an annoying part to get working: there is no super simple way to do such sleeps precisely.

   Possible methods include:

   - PIT (used in my example)
   - HPET
   - calibrate the time of a busy loop with the above, and use it instead

   Related: [How to display a number on the screen and and sleep for one second with DOS x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971405/how-to-display-a-number-on-the-screen-and-and-sleep-for-one-second-with-dos-x86)
7. I think the initial processor needs to be in protected mode for this to work as we write to address `0FEE00300H` which is too high for 16-bits
8. To communicate between processors, we can use a spinlock on the main process, and modify the lock from the second core.

   We should ensure that memory write back is done, e.g. through `wbinvd`.

#### Shared state between processors

8.7.1 "State of the Logical Processors" says:

> The following features are part of the architectural state of logical processors within Intel 64 or IA-32 processors
>   supporting Intel Hyper-Threading Technology. The features can be subdivided into three groups:
>
> - Duplicated for each logical processor
> - Shared by logical processors in a physical processor
> - Shared or duplicated, depending on the implementation
>
> The following features are duplicated for each logical processor:
>
> - General purpose registers (EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, ESP, and EBP)
> - Segment registers (CS, DS, SS, ES, FS, and GS)
> - EFLAGS and EIP registers. Note that the CS and EIP/RIP registers for each logical processor point to the
>     instruction stream for the thread being executed by the logical processor.
> - x87 FPU registers (ST0 through ST7, status word, control word, tag word, data operand pointer, and instruction
>     pointer)
> - MMX registers (MM0 through MM7)
> - XMM registers (XMM0 through XMM7) and the MXCSR register
> - Control registers and system table pointer registers (GDTR, LDTR, IDTR, task register)
> - Debug registers (DR0, DR1, DR2, DR3, DR6, DR7) and the debug control MSRs
> - Machine check global status (IA32_MCG_STATUS) and machine check capability (IA32_MCG_CAP) MSRs
> - Thermal clock modulation and ACPI Power management control MSRs
> - Time stamp counter MSRs
> - Most of the other MSR registers, including the page attribute table (PAT). See the exceptions below.
> - Local APIC registers.
> - Additional general purpose registers (R8-R15), XMM registers (XMM8-XMM15), control register, IA32_EFER on
>     Intel 64 processors.
>
> The following features are shared by logical processors:
>
> - Memory type range registers (MTRRs)
>
> Whether the following features are shared or duplicated is implementation-specific:
>
> - IA32_MISC_ENABLE MSR (MSR address 1A0H)
> - Machine check architecture (MCA) MSRs (except for the IA32_MCG_STATUS and IA32_MCG_CAP MSRs)
> - Performance monitoring control and counter MSRs

Cache sharing is discussed at:

- [How are cache memories shared in multicore Intel CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944966/how-are-cache-memories-shared-in-multicore-intel-cpus/33510874#33510874)
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802565/multiple-threads-and-cpu-cache
- [Can multiple CPU's / cores access the same RAM simultaneously?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/183686/can-multiple-cpus-cores-access-the-same-ram-simutaneously)

Intel hyperthreads have greater cache and pipeline sharing than separate cores: https://superuser.com/questions/133082/hyper-threading-and-dual-core-whats-the-difference/995858#995858

#### Linux kernel 4.2

The main initialization action seems to be at `arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c`.

### ARM minimal runnable baremetal example

Here I provide a minimal runnable ARMv8 aarch64 example for QEMU:

```
.global mystart
mystart:
    /* Reset spinlock. */
    mov x0, #0
    ldr x1, =spinlock
    str x0, [x1]

    /* Read cpu id into x1.
     * TODO: cores beyond 4th?
     * Mnemonic: Main Processor ID Register
     */
    mrs x1, mpidr_el1
    ands x1, x1, 3
    beq cpu0_only
cpu1_only:
    /* Only CPU 1 reaches this point and sets the spinlock. */
    mov x0, 1
    ldr x1, =spinlock
    str x0, [x1]
    /* Ensure that CPU 0 sees the write right now.
     * Optional, but could save some useless CPU 1 loops.
     */
    dmb sy
    /* Wake up CPU 0 if it is sleeping on wfe.
     * Optional, but could save power on a real system.
     */
    sev
cpu1_sleep_forever:
    /* Hint CPU 1 to enter low power mode.
     * Optional, but could save power on a real system.
     */
    wfe
    b cpu1_sleep_forever
cpu0_only:
    /* Only CPU 0 reaches this point. */

    /* Wake up CPU 1 from initial sleep!
     * See:https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat#psci
     */
    /* PCSI function identifier: CPU_ON. */
    ldr w0, =0xc4000003
    /* Argument 1: target_cpu */
    mov x1, 1
    /* Argument 2: entry_point_address */
    ldr x2, =cpu1_only
    /* Argument 3: context_id */
    mov x3, 0
    /* Unused hvc args: the Linux kernel zeroes them,
     * but I don't think it is required.
     */
    hvc 0

spinlock_start:
    ldr x0, spinlock
    /* Hint CPU 0 to enter low power mode. */
    wfe
    cbz x0, spinlock_start

    /* Semihost exit. */
    mov x1, 0x26
    movk x1, 2, lsl 16
    str x1, [sp, 0]
    mov x0, 0
    str x0, [sp, 8]
    mov x1, sp
    mov w0, 0x18
    hlt 0xf000

spinlock:
    .skip 8
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/ba2976cc7f3fedde691f771d38fcdb4ce2e12b94/baremetal/arch/aarch64/multicore.S).

Assemble and run:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc \
  -mcpu=cortex-a57 \
  -nostdlib \
  -nostartfiles \
  -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x40000000 \
  -Wl,-N \
  -o aarch64.elf \
  -T link.ld \
  aarch64.S \
;
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -machine virt \
  -cpu cortex-a57 \
  -d in_asm \
  -kernel aarch64.elf \
  -nographic \
  -semihosting \
  -smp 2 \
;
```

In this example, we put CPU 0 in a spinlock loop, and it only exits with CPU 1 releases the spinlock.

After the spinlock, CPU 0 then does a [semihost exit call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990487/how-to-cleanly-exit-qemu-after-executing-bare-metal-program-without-user-interve/49930361#49930361) which makes QEMU quit.

If you start QEMU with just one CPU with `-smp 1`, then simulation just hangs forever on the spinlock.

CPU 1 is woken up with the PSCI interface, more details at: [ARM: Start/Wakeup/Bringup the other CPU cores/APs and pass execution start address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055754/arm-start-wakeup-bringup-the-other-cpu-cores-aps-and-pass-execution-start-addre/53473447#53473447)

The [upstream version](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/ba2976cc7f3fedde691f771d38fcdb4ce2e12b94/baremetal/arch/aarch64/multicore.S) also has a few tweaks to make it work on gem5, so you can experiment with performance characteristics as well.

I haven't tested it on real hardware, so and I'm not sure how portable this is. The following Raspberry Pi bibliography might be of interest:

- https://github.com/bztsrc/raspi3-tutorial/tree/a3f069b794aeebef633dbe1af3610784d55a0efa/02_multicorec
- https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/a09771a1d5a0b53d8e7a461948dc226c5467aeec/multi00
- https://github.com/LdB-ECM/Raspberry-Pi/blob/3b628a2c113b3997ffdb408db03093b2953e4961/Multicore/SmartStart64.S
- https://github.com/LdB-ECM/Raspberry-Pi/blob/3b628a2c113b3997ffdb408db03093b2953e4961/Multicore/SmartStart32.S

This document provides some guidance on using ARM synchronization primitives which you can then use to do fun things with multiple cores: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/DHT0008A_arm_synchronization_primitives.pdf

Tested on Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0, Binutils 2.31.1, QEMU 2.12.0.

### Next steps for more convenient programmability

The previous examples wake up secondary CPU and do basic memory synchronization with dedicated instructions, which is a good start.

But to make multicore systems easy to program, e.g. like [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755) `pthreads`, you would also need to go into the following more involved topics:

- setup interrupts and run a timer that periodically decides which thread will run now. This is known as [preemptive multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Preemptive_multitasking).

  Such system also needs to save and restore thread registers as they are started and stopped.

  It is also possible to have non-preemptive multitasking systems, but those might require you to modify your code so that every threads yields (e.g. with a `pthread_yield` implementation), and it becomes harder to balance workloads.

  Here are some simplistic bare metal timer examples:

  - [x86 PIT](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/6dc9a73830fc05358d8d66128f740ef9906f7677/pit.S)
- deal with memory conflicts. Notably, each thread will need a [unique stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584089/what-is-the-function-of-the-push-pop-instructions-used-on-registers-in-x86-ass/33583134#33583134) if you want to code in C or other high level languages.

  You could just limit threads to have a fixed maximum stack size, but the nicer way to deal with this is with [paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work) which allows for efficient "unlimited size" stacks.

  Here is [a naive aarch64 baremetal example that would blow up if the stack grows too deep](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/d6d7f15c912ed6371c8cf15a93f43488d6fc5efb/baremetal/arch/aarch64/multicore.c)

Those are some good reasons to use the Linux kernel or some other operating system :-)

### Userland memory synchronization primitives

Although thread start / stop / management is generally beyond userland scope, you can however use assembly instructions from userland threads to synchronize memory accesses without potentially more expensive system calls.

You should of course prefer using libraries that portably wrap these low level primitives. The C++ standard itself has made great advances on the [`<mutex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`<atomic>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/atomic) headers, and in particular with [`std::memory_order`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order). I'm not sure if it covers all possible memory semantics achievable, but it just might.

The more subtle semantics are particularly relevant in the context of [lock free data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm), which can offer performance benefits in certain cases. To implement those, you will likely have to learn a bit about the different types of memory barriers: https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/

Boost for example has some lock free container implementations at: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/lockfree.html

Such userland instructions also appear to be used to implement the Linux `futex` system call, which is one of the main synchronization primitives in Linux. `man futex` 4.15 reads:

> The  futex()  system  call  provides  a method for waiting until a certain condition becomes true.  It is typically used as a
>   blocking construct in the context of shared-memory synchronization.  When using futexes, the majority of the  synchronization
>   operations are performed in user space.  A user-space program employs the futex() system call only when it is likely that the
>   program has to block for a longer time until the condition becomes true.  Other futex() operations can be used  to  wake  any
>   processes or threads waiting for a particular condition.

The syscall name itself means "Fast Userspace XXX".

Here is a minimal useless C++ x86_64 / aarch64 example with inline assembly that illustrates basic usage of such instructions mostly for fun:

main.cpp

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::atomic_ulong my_atomic_ulong(0);
unsigned long my_non_atomic_ulong = 0;
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__aarch64__)
unsigned long my_arch_atomic_ulong = 0;
unsigned long my_arch_non_atomic_ulong = 0;
#endif
size_t niters;

void threadMain() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < niters; ++i) {
        my_atomic_ulong++;
        my_non_atomic_ulong++;
#if defined(__x86_64__)
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "incq %0;"
            : "+m" (my_arch_non_atomic_ulong)
            :
            :
        );
        // https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat#x86-lock-prefix
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "lock;"
            "incq %0;"
            : "+m" (my_arch_atomic_ulong)
            :
            :
        );
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "add %0, %0, 1;"
            : "+r" (my_arch_non_atomic_ulong)
            :
            :
        );
        // https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat#arm-lse
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "ldadd %[inc], xzr, [%[addr]];"
            : "=m" (my_arch_atomic_ulong)
            : [inc] "r" (1),
              [addr] "r" (&my_arch_atomic_ulong)
            :
        );
#endif
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t nthreads;
    if (argc > 1) {
        nthreads = std::stoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        nthreads = 2;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        niters = std::stoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        niters = 10000;
    }
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(nthreads);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(threadMain);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
        threads[i].join();
    assert(my_atomic_ulong.load() == nthreads * niters);
    // We can also use the atomics direclty through `operator T` conversion.
    assert(my_atomic_ulong == my_atomic_ulong.load());
    std::cout << "my_non_atomic_ulong " << my_non_atomic_ulong << std::endl;
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__aarch64__)
    assert(my_arch_atomic_ulong == nthreads * niters);
    std::cout << "my_arch_non_atomic_ulong " << my_arch_non_atomic_ulong << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/77c7df5fcded3a87aaed1de0f8d2335ba909d574/userland/cpp/atomic.cpp).

Possible output:

```
my_non_atomic_ulong 15264
my_arch_non_atomic_ulong 15267
```

From this we see that the x86 LOCK prefix / aarch64 `LDADD` instruction made the addition atomic: without it we have race conditions on many of the adds, and the total count at the end is less than the synchronized 20000.

See also:

- x86

  - LOCK [What does the "lock" instruction mean in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891067/what-does-the-lock-instruction-mean-in-x86-assembly/56803909#56803909)
  - PAUSE [How does x86 pause instruction work in spinlock *and* can it be used in other scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725676/how-does-x86-pause-instruction-work-in-spinlock-and-can-it-be-used-in-other-sc)
- ARM

  - LDXR/STXR, LDAXR/STLXR: [ARM64: LDXR/STXR vs LDAXR/STLXR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535058/arm64-ldxr-stxr-vs-ldaxr-stlxr)
  - LDADD and other atomic v8.1 load modify store instructions: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0801g/alc1476202791033.html
  - WFE / SVE: [WFE instruction handling in ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825145/wfe-instruction-handling-in-arm)
- [What exactly is std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978324/what-exactly-is-stdatomic/58904448#58904448)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04 amd64 and with QEMU aarch64 user mode.

Comment: What assembler do you use to compile your example? GAS doesn't seem to like your `#include` (takes it as a comment), NASM, FASM, YASM don't know AT&T syntax so it can't be them... so what is it?

Comment: @Ruslan `gcc`, `#include` comes from the C preprocessor. Use the `Makefile` provided as explained in the getting started section: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/8ceb4b27a68d44318b58db4c48ccf8b95eca9f1b/getting-started.md If that does not work, do open a GitHub issue.

Comment: on x86, what happen if a core realize there is no more processes ready to run in the queue ? (which might happen from time to time on a idle system). Does the core spinlock on shared memory structure until there is a new task ? (probably not good is it will use lot of power) does it call something like HLT to sleep until there is an interrupt ? (in that case who is responsible to wake up that core ?)

Comment: @tigrou not sure, but I find it extremely likely that the Linux implementation will put it in a power state until next (likely timer) interrupt, especially on ARM where power is key. I would try quickly to see if that can be observed concretely easily with an instruction trace of a simulator running Linux, it might be: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/50ac89b779363774325c81157ec8b9a6bdb50a2f#gem5-tracing

Comment: Some information (specific to x86 / Windows) can be found [here](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=7) (see "Idle Thread"). TL;DR : when no runnable thread exists on a CPU, CPU is dispatched to an idle thread. Along with some other tasks, it will ultimately call the registered power management processor idle routine (via a driver provided by CPU vendor, eg : Intel). This might transition CPU to some deeper C-state (eg : C0 -> C3) in order reduce power consumption.

Comment: Holy shit, Ciro made it his masters degree to write OP an answer. What a long and detailed answer, thanks!

Answer (score 48):

As I understand it, each "core" is a complete processor, with its own register set. Basically, the BIOS starts you off with one core running, and then the operating system can "start" other cores by initializing them and pointing them at the code to run, etc.

Synchronization is done by the OS. Generally, each processor is running a different process for the OS, so the multi-threading functionality of the operating system is in charge of deciding which process gets to touch which memory, and what to do in the case of a memory collision.

Comment: which does beg the question though: What instructions are available to the operating system to do this?

Comment: There's a set of priviledged instructions for that, but it's the problem of operating system, not the application code. If application code wants to be multithreaded it has to call operating system functions to do the "magic".

Comment: The BIOS will usually identify how many cores are available and will pass this information to the OS when asked. There are standards which the BIOS (and hardware) must conform to such that access to hardware specifics (processors, cores, PCI bus, PCI cards, mouse, keyboard, graphics, ISA, PCI-E/X, memory etc) for different PCs looks the same from the OS's point of view. If the BIOS doesn't report that there are four cores the OS will usually assume that there is only one. There might even be a BIOS setting to experiment with.

Comment: @sharptooth, That's not the question. The question is what x86 instructions does the OS software use to do it?

Comment: That's cool and all but what if you are writing a bare-metal program?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett, ? What's that even?  Reiterating, when we say "leave it to the OS", we are avoiding the question because the question is how does the OS do it then? What assembly instructions does it use?

Comment: If I was writing code for a micro-controller that doesn't have an OS, is what I mean by 'bare-metal'.   If you have used [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/) with [Zinc](https://github.com/hackndev/zinc), you know what I am talking about.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett, Yep we're saying the same thing. The question is  what does the OS do to make it work.

Answer (score 44):

#### The Unofficial SMP FAQ  [image: stack overflow logo]

---

*Once upon a time, to write x86 assembler, for example, you would have instructions stating "load the EDX register with the value 5", "increment the EDX" register, etc. With modern CPUs that have 4 cores (or even more), at the machine code level does it just look like there are 4 separate CPUs (i.e. are there just 4 distinct "EDX" registers) ?*

**Exactly. There are 4 sets of registers, including 4 separate instruction pointers.**

*If so, when you say "increment the EDX register", what determines which CPU's EDX register is incremented?*

**The CPU that executed that instruction, naturally. Think of it as 4 entirely different microprocessors that are simply sharing the same memory.**

*Is there a "CPU context" or "thread" concept in x86 assembler now?*

**No. The assembler just translates instructions like it always did. No changes there.**

*How does communication/synchronization between the cores work?*

**Since they share the same memory, it's mostly a matter of program logic. Although there now is an [inter-processor interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-processor_interrupt) mechanism, it's not necessary and was not originally present in the first dual-CPU x86 systems.**

*If you were writing an operating system, what mechanism is exposed via hardware to allow you to schedule execution on different cores?*

**The scheduler actually doesn't change, except that it is slightly more carefully about critical sections and the types of locks used. Before SMP, kernel code would eventually call the scheduler, which would look at the run queue and pick a process to run as the next thread. (Processes to the kernel look a lot like threads.)  The SMP kernel runs the exact same code, one thread at a time, it's just that now critical section locking needs to be SMP-safe to be sure two cores can't accidentally pick the same PID.**

*Is it some special privileged instruction(s)?*

**No. The cores are just all running in the same memory with the same old instructions.**

*If you were writing an optimizing compiler/bytecode VM for a multicore CPU, what would you need to know specifically about, say, x86 to make it generate code that runs efficiently across all the cores?*

**You run the same code as before. It's the Unix or Windows kernel that needed to change.**

*You could summarize my question as "What changes have been made to x86 machine code to support multi-core functionality?"*

**Nothing was necessary. The first SMP systems used the exact same instruction set as uniprocessors. Now, there has been a great deal of x86 architecture evolution and zillions of new instructions to make things go faster, but none were *necessary* for SMP.**

For more information, see the [Intel Multiprocessor Specification](http://download.intel.com/design/pentium/datashts/24201606.pdf).

---

*Update:* all the follow-up questions can be answered by just completely accepting that an *n*-way multicore CPU is almost<sup>1</sup> exactly the same thing as *n* separate processors that just share the same memory.<sup>2</sup>  There was an important question not asked: *how is a program written to run on more than one core for more performance?* And the answer is: it is written using a thread library like [Pthreads.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) Some thread libraries use "green threads" that are not visible to the OS, and those won't get separate cores, but as long as the thread library uses kernel thread features then your threaded program will automatically be multicore.

---

<sup>1. For backwards compatibility, only the first core starts up at reset, and a few driver-type things need to be done to fire up the remaining ones.
2. They also share all the peripherals, naturally.</sup>

Comment: I always think "thread" is a software concept, which makes me difficult to understand multi-core processor, the problem is , how can codes tell a core "I'm going to create a thread running in core 2"? Is there any special assembly code to do it ?

Comment: @demonguy: No, there's no special instruction for anything like that.  You ask the OS to run your thread on a specific core by setting an affinity mask (which says "this thread can run on this set of logical cores").  It's completely a software issue.  Each CPU core (hardware thread) is independently running Linux (or Windows).  To work together with the other hardware threads, they use shared data structures.  But you never "directly" start a thread on a different CPU.  You tell the OS you'd like to have a new thread, and it makes a note in a data structure which the OS on another core sees.

Comment: I can tell os it, but how os put codes onto specific core ?

Comment: @demonguy ... (simplified) ... each core shares the OS image and starts running it in the same place. So, for 8 cores, that's 8 "hardware processes" running in the kernel. Each one calls the same scheduler function that checks the process table for a runnable process or thread.  (That's the *run queue.*) Meanwhile, programs with threads work without awareness of the underlying SMP nature. They just fork(2) or something and let the kernel know they want to run. Essentially, the core finds the process, rather than the process finding the core.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, Per your answer, are you telling him to write his own OS?

Comment: @Pacerier, well, no.  Just trying to explain SMP really.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, Re "it's not necessary and was not originally present in the first dual-CPU x86 systems": How then are you able to interrupt another core? Or does the other cores need to repeatedly check the memory for a "signal" every few seconds?

Comment: You don't actually need to interrupt one core  from another. Think about it this way: everything you needed to communicate before _was_ communicated just fine with software mechanisms. The same software mechanisms  continue to work.  So, pipes, kernel calls, sleep/wakeup, all that stuff ... they still work like before. Not every process is running on the same CPU but they have the same data structures for communication as they had before. The effort in going SMP is mostly confined to making the old locks work in a more parallel environment.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, Per the answer, you answered his subquestion on optimizing with  "*It's the Unix or Windows kernel that needed to change*". **But how then?** That's the crux of the question as he's writing the "OS", the VM that sits below these "application OSes". What do these "*and zillions of new instructions to make things go faster*" do basically?

Answer (score 11):

> If you were writing an optimizing
>   compiler/bytecode VM for a multicore
>   CPU, what would you need to know
>   specifically about, say, x86 to make
>   it generate code that runs efficiently
>   across all the cores?

As someone who writes optimizing compiler/bytecode VMs I may be able to help you here.

You do not need to know anything specifically about x86 to make it generate code that runs efficiently across all the cores.

However, you may need to know about cmpxchg and friends in order to write code that runs **correctly** across all the cores.  Multicore programming requires the use of synchronisation and communication between threads of execution.

You may need to know something about x86 to make it generate code that runs efficiently on x86 in general.

There are other things it would be useful for you to learn:

You should learn about the facilities the OS (Linux or Windows or OSX) provides to allow you to run multiple threads.  You should learn about parallelization APIs such as OpenMP and Threading Building Blocks, or OSX 10.6 "Snow Leopard"'s forthcoming "Grand Central".

You should consider if your compiler should be auto-parallelising, or if the author of the applications compiled by your compiler needs to add special syntax or API calls into his program to take advantage of the multiple cores.

Comment: Don't have several popular VMs like .NET and Java have a problem that their main GC process is covered in locks and fundamentally singlethreaded?

Answer (score 9):

Each Core executes from a different memory area. Your operating system will point a core at your program and the core will execute your program. Your program will not be aware that there are more than one core or on which core it is executing.

There is also no additional instruction only available to the Operating System. These cores are identical to single core chips. Each Core runs a part of the Operating System that will handle communication to common memory areas used for information interchange to find the next memory area to execute.

This is a simplification but it gives you the basic idea of how it is done. [More about multicores and multiprocessors](http://www.embedded.com/products/integratedcircuits/173400008?_requestid=279459)  on Embedded.com has lots of information about this topic ... This topic get complicated very quickly!

Comment: I think one should distinguish a bit more carefully here how multicore works in general, and how much the OS influences. "Each core executes from a different memory areay" is too misleading in my opinion. First and foremost, using multiple cores in principles does not need this, and you can easily see that for a threaded program you'd WANT two cores two work on the same text and data segments (while each core also needs individual resources like stack).

Comment: @ShiDoiSi That is why my answer contains the text *"This is a simplification"*.

Answer (score 5):

The assembly code will translate into machine code that will be executed on one core. If you want it to be multithreaded you will have to use operating system primitives to start this code on different processors several times or different pieces of code on different cores - each core will execute a separate thread. Each thread will only see one core it is currently executing on.

Comment: I was going to say something like this, but then how does the OS allocate threads to cores? I imagine there are some privileged assembly instructions which accomplish this. If so, I think that is the answer the author is looking for.

Comment: There's no instruction for that, that's the duty of operating system scheduler. There are operating system functions like SetThreadAffinityMask in Win32 and the code can call them, but it's operating system stuff and affects the scheduler, it's not a processor instruction.

Comment: There must be an OpCode or else the operating system wouldn't be able to do it either.

Comment: Not really an opcode for scheduling - it's more like you get one copy of the OS per processor, sharing a memory space; whenever a core re-enters the kernel (syscall or interrupt), it looks at the same data structures in memory to decide what thread to run next.

Comment: @A.Levy: When you start a thread with an affinity that only lets it run on a different core, it doesn't *immediately* move to the other core.  It has its context saved to memory, just like a normal context switch.  The other hardware threads see its entry in the scheduler data structures, and one of them will eventually decide that it will run the thread.  So from the perspective of the first core: **you write to a shared data structure and eventually OS code on another core (hardware thread) will notice it and run it.**

Answer (score 3):

It's not done in machine instructions at all; the cores pretend to be distinct CPUs and don't have any special capabilities for talking to one another. There are two ways they communicate:

- they share the physical address space. The hardware handles cache coherency, so one CPU writes to a memory address which another reads.
- they share an APIC (programmable interrupt controller). This is memory mapped into the physical address space, and can be used by one processor to control the others, turn them on or off, send interrupts, etc.

http://www.cheesecake.org/sac/smp.html is a good reference with a silly url.

Comment: They don't in fact share an APIC.  Each logical CPU has its own one.  The APICs communicate between themselves, but they are separate.

Comment: They synchronize (rather than communicate) in one basic way and that is through the LOCK prefix (the instruction "xchg mem,reg" contains an implicit lock request) which runs to the lock pin which runs to all buses effectively telling them that the CPU (actually any bus-mastering device) wants exclusive access to the bus. Eventually a signal will return to the LOCKA (acknowledge) pin telling the CPU that it now has exclusive access to the bus. Since external devices are much slower than the internal workings of the CPU a LOCK/LOCKA sequence may require many hundreds of CPU cycles to complete.

Answer (score 2):

I think the questioner probably wants to make a program run faster by having multiple cores work on it in parallel. That's what I would want anyway but all the answers leave me no wiser. However, I think I get this: You can't synchronize different threads down to instruction execution time accuracy.  So you can't get 4 cores to do a multiply on four different array elements in parallel to speed up processing by 4:1. Rather, you have to look at your program as comprising major blocks that execute sequentially like

1. Do an FFT on some data
2. Put the result in a matrix and find the Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of it
3. Sort the latter by eigenvalue
4. repeat from step one with new data

What you can do is run step 2 on the results of step 1 while running step one in a different core on new data,  and running step 3 on the results of step2 in a different core while step 2 is running on the next data and step 1 is running on the data after that.
You can do this in Compaq Visual Fortran and Intel Fortran which is an evolution of CVF  by writing three separate  programs/ subroutines for the three steps and instead of one "calling" the next it calls an API  to start its thread.
They can share data by using COMMON  which will be COMMON  data memory to all threads.
You have to study the manual till your head hurts and experiment until you get it to work but I have succeeded once at least.

Comment: Some single problems are large enough to parallelize, e.g. a large matmul or a large FFT (http://www.fftw.org/parallel/parallel-fftw.html).  Some libraries provide parallelized implementations.  But yes, good answer that threads are only good for somewhat-coarse parallelism because of the overhead it takes to hand out work and collect results.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between a single- and a multi-threaded application is that the former has one stack and the latter has one for each thread. Code is generated somewhat differently since the compiler will assume that the data and stack segment registers (ds and ss) are not equal. This means that indirection through the ebp and esp registers that default to the ss register won't also default to ds (because ds!=ss). Conversely, indirection through the other registers which default to ds won't default to ss.

The threads share everything else including data and code areas. They also share lib routines so make sure that they are thread-safe. A procedure that sorts an area in RAM can be multi-threaded to speed things up. The threads will then be accessing, comparing and ordering data in the same physical memory area and executing the same code but using different local variables to control their respective part of the sort. This of course is because the threads have different stacks where the local variables are contained. This type of programming requires careful tuning of the code so that inter-core data collisions (in caches and RAM) are reduced which in turn results in a code which is faster with two or more threads than it is with just one. Of course, an un-tuned code will often be faster with one processor than with two or more. To debug is more challenging because the standard "int 3" breakpoint will not be applicable since you want to interrupt a specific thread and not all of them. Debug register breakpoints do not solve this problem either unless you can set them on the specific processor executing the specific thread you want to interrupt.

Other multi-threaded code may involve different threads running in different parts of the program. This type of programming does not require the same kind of tuning and is therefore much easier to learn.

Answer (score 0):

What has been added on every multiprocessing-capable architecture compared to the single-processor variants that came before them are instructions to synchronize between cores.  Also, you have instructions to deal with cache coherency, flushing buffers, and similar low-level operations an OS has to deal with.  In the case of simultaneous multithreaded architectures like IBM POWER6, IBM Cell, Sun Niagara, and Intel "Hyperthreading", you also tend to see new instructions to prioritize between threads (like setting priorities and explicitly yielding the processor when there is nothing to do).

But the basic single-thread semantics are the same, you just add extra facilities to handle synchronization and communication with other cores.