# How can I detect the number of cores in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86

I am writing a very simple operating system as a learning tool for myself.  My current task is detecting as much about the hardware as possible.

I have so far been able to find a lot of information about the CPU using the CPUID instruction.  The one thing I can't seem to find is the number or physical and/or logical cores.  Is there a way to do this using a combination of x86 assembly and C?

I am writing the operating system, so the code can be run in supervisor mode, and  there are no system libraries to query for this information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to find all of the processors in a system, you must parse either the ACPI tables or Intel's MP configuration table. See [Bringing SMP to your UP Operating System](http://www.cheesecake.org/sac/smp.html) for a tutorial on using the MP configuration table to find and start other processors. Find more information on ACPI at http://www.acpi.info/spec.htm. You may also want to check out [Detecting CPU Topology](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_CPU_Topology_%2880x86%29), which can tell you which processors and cores are on which physical chip within a system.

When working on your OS, http://wiki.osdev.org will be your best friend. It is full of information on all of the different parts of operating system development, including common hardware and tools.

Comment: You can see how Mac OS X solves the problem in [xnu/osfmk/i386/cpuid.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.9.37/osfmk/i386/cpuid.c) (search for `core_count`) and [xnu/osfmk/i386/cpu_topology.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.9.37/osfmk/i386/cpu_topology.c).