# Question regarding Assembly and computer programs

Tags: assembly, linker, executable

I read this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language

It says:

> Take, for example, the instruction that tells an x86/IA-32 processor
>   to move an immediate 8-bit value into a register. The binary code for
>   this instruction is 10110 followed by a 3-bit identifier for which
>   register to use. The identifier for the AL register is 000, so the
>   following machine code loads the AL register with the data
>   01100001.[4]
>
> `10110000 01100001`

It explains how it is easier to write it as:

```
MOV AL, 61h       ; Load AL with 97 decimal (61 hex)
```

Now here are my question(s).

So, computer programs/executables are just binary data (0's and 1's)?

When viewed with a disassembler like OllyDbg it just tries to revert those 0's and 1's back to some Assembly (Intel?) language and the output is mostly correct?

If I have this `10110000 01100001` program on my SSD and I write a C#/PHP/wtvr application that reads the contents of the file and output them as bits, will I see these exact `10110000 01100001` figures?

How does the operating system do the actual "execution"? How does it tell the processor that "hey, take these bits and run them"? Can I do that in C#/C++ directly?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Linux execution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, computer programs/executables are just binary data (0's and 1's)?

Yes like images, videos and other data.

> When viewed with a disassembler like OllyDbg it just tries to revert those 0's and 1's back to some Assembly (Intel?) language and the output is mostly correct?

Yes, in this exact case it will always be correct as `mov al, 61h` is always assembled to `0xB0 0x61` (in [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) and other places usually written as `B0 61`) in 16-, 32- and 64-bit mode. Note that `0xB0 0x61` = `0b10110000 0b01100001`.

You can find the encoding for different instructions in Volume 2A. For example here it is "B0+ rb MOV r8, imm8 E Valid Valid Move imm8 to r8." on page 3-644.

Other instructions have different meanings depend on whether they are interpreted in 16/32 or 64-bit mode. Consider this short sequence of bytes: `66 83 C0 04 41 80 C0 05`

In 16-bit mode they mean:

```
00000000  6683C004          add eax,byte +0x4
00000004  41                inc cx
00000005  80C005            add al,0x5
```

In 32-bit mode they mean:

```
00000000  6683C004          add ax,byte +0x4
00000004  41                inc ecx
00000005  80C005            add al,0x5
```

And finally in 64-bit mode:

```
00000000  6683C004          add ax,byte +0x4
00000004  4180C005          add r8b,0x5
```

So the instructions cannot always be disassembled correctly without knowing the context (this is not even taking into account that other things than code can reside in the text segment and the code can do nasty stuff like generate code on the fly or self-modify).

> If I have this 10110000 01100001 program on my SSD and I write a C#/PHP/wtvr application that reads the contents of the file and output them as bits, will I see these exact 10110000 01100001 figures?

Yes, in the sense that if the application contains the `mov al, 61h` instruction the file will contain the bytes `0xB0` and `0x61`.

> How does the operating system do the actual "execution"? How does it tell the processor that "hey, take these bits and run them"? Can I do that in C#/C++ directly?

After loading the code into memory (and the memory is correctly setup permission-wise) it can just jump to or call it and have it run. One thing you have to realize even though the operating system is just another program it is a special program since it got to the processor first! It runs in a special supervisor (or hypervisor) mode that allows it to things normal (user) programs aren't allowed to. Like set up [preemptive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) that makes sure processes are automatically yielded.

The first processor is also responsible for waking up the other cores/processors on a multi-core/multi-processor machine. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980999/what-does-multicore-assembly-language-look-like) SO question.

To call code you load yourself directly in C++ (I don't think it is possible in C# without resorting to unsafe/native code) requires platform specific tricks. For Windows you probably want to look at [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and under linux `mprotect(2)`. Or perhaps more realistically from a file which is the mapped using either [this process for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366546%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or `mmap(2)` for linux.

Answer (score 1):

that are a lot of questions:

Yes, computer programs/executables are just binary data 0/1s.

Yes, the disassembler tries to make sense of 0/1s... and it uses additional knowledge about the file format (EXE follows usually the PE spec, COM is different spec etc.) and the OS the binary is supposed to run on and the APIs available etc. .

These two bytes (one instruction with a parameter) would read exactly like that... although it depends on program they are part of - as mentioned different file types follow different specifications.

Usually the OS loads the file and processes its content according to the specification - for example rearranges some memory areas etc. . Then it marks the memory areas that contains executable code as executable and does a JMP or CALL to the address of the first instruction of the so-called entry-point (again this differs depending on the file format / specification at hand).

In C# you don't deal with assembly as a language but with "byte code" (IL instructions)... you can emit thos or load thos via Framework methos etc.
In c++ you could deal directly with assembly if you really want to but that is not portable and could get complicated... so you usually only do that when the gain is really worth it (like a needed performance boost by factor 10).

Comment: Very interesting. What's the executable format specification that Unix OS uses? So when the OS executes the file, and does that `JPM` or `CALL`, wouldn't it block all other processes? Or does the executable `yield` processor time for other processes?

Comment: the format used in Unix OSs is not 100% identical since there are several flavors (used to be COFF, is lately ELF - seee http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)... No the OS has a so-called scheduler which takes case of giving each process a slice of the processor time... and the proceses are started on a different thread so the OS does not get blocked etc. processor architecture aids in that for example by havin the OS on more privileged "ring" (x86 32 and 64 bit processors...).

Answer (score 1):

> So, computer programs/executables are just binary data (0's and 1's)?

YES.

> When viewed with a disassembler like OllyDbg it just tries to revert
>   those 0's and 1's back to some Assembly (Intel?) language and the
>   output is mostly correct?

YES. Except that if the binary data represents code for the cpu the disassembler is designed for, the the output will be totally correct, not just 'mostly' correct.

> If I have this 10110000 01100001 program on my SSD and I write a
>   C#/PHP/wtvr application that reads the contents of the file and output
>   them as bits, will I see these exact 10110000 01100001 figures?

YES

> How does the operating system do the actual "execution"? How does it
>   tell the processor that "hey, take these bits and run them"?

The operating system is just a program like any other, it is instructions being executed on the processor. Simplistically when the operating system executes the code, all it does is jump to the start address of where the code is situated and hence the processor now begins executing whatever code is at that location.

> Can I do that in C#/C++ directly?

Don't forget that C is compiled down to assembly language when it executes and at the point it is executed, it is no different to any other program that could run on a given CPU. Yes, you can use inline assembly for example to jump to a given memory location and execute the code.

Comment: Thank you, I have the same question for you as I had for Yahia: when the OS executes the file, and does that `JPM` or `CALL`, wouldn't it block all other processes? Or does the executable `yield` processor time for other processes? And since the OS is just another program (1's and 0's), wouldn't the OS also block? How do multi-core CPUs make things different?

Comment: The specifics depend on the precise nature of the hardware you are running on and the question is really too broad for a simple stack overflow response.