# Reading and Printing content from a txt file using Mips Assembly

Tags: assembly, printing, mips

I'm trying to read and print the content inside a .txt file.
Later i'd like to read the dumped file from mips aswell.
I see the code and it seems ok but nothing is outputed...

```
.data  
myFile: .asciiz "teste.txt"      # filename for input
buffer: .space 1024
.text

# Open file for reading

li   $v0, 13          # system call for open file
la   $a0, myFile      # input file name
li   $a1, 0           # flag for reading
li   $a2, 0           # mode is ignored
syscall               # open a file 
move $s0, $v0         # save the file descriptor  


# reading from file just opened

li   $v0, 14        # system call for reading from file
move $a0, $s0       # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer    # address of buffer from which to read
li   $a2,  11       # hardcoded buffer length
syscall             # read from file


# Printing File Content
li  $v0, 4          # system Call for PRINT STRING
la  $a0, buffer     # buffer contains the values
syscall             # print int

li $v0, 10      # Finish the Program
syscall
```

Comment: Single-step your code in the debugger.  Check the syscall return values (in the debugger) for errors.  Or better, trace the system calls.  IDK if MARS or SPIM have that, but Linux does (`strace`).  Of course Linux uses different system calls than MARS or SPIM.

Comment: Anyway, this would be a much better [mcve] if you include register values from the debugger at various points.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have no idea how to debbug my code here, biseds the F3 + F7, F7, F7...  
Also, is there a way to be sure the file is read correctly? Because even if I change the file name to an invalid one there is no erros/warnings shown...

Comment: @PeterCordes Now I'm using `blq $v0, -1, error` to check if the `$v0` returns negative value, which means error while opening the file... Is there  way to print the error message?

Comment: Most debuggers will show you register contents and memory.  Check the documentation.  Look at syscall documentation to find out which error return values mean what.  (In Linux, syscalls return -errno, so for example open with a wrong filename would return `-ENOENT`, which is `-2` on x86-64 Linux.  See asm-generic/errno-base.h.  But Mars or SPIM system calls probably use different constants, even if they use the same `-error_code` convention.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem was about the `path` of my file.
I thought the path would start from the  source code, but it starts from the `.jar` file.

All I had to do is provide a fullPath with double`\\`

```
.data
myFile: .asciiz "c:\\Users\\johnDoe\\Documents\\Assembly\\test.txt" # filename for input
```