# ARM64: LDXR/STXR vs LDAXR/STLXR

Tags: arm, atomic, arm64

On iOS, there are two similar functions, `OSAtomicAdd32` and `OSAtomicAdd32Barrier`. I'm wondering when you would need the `Barrier` variant.

Disassembled, they are:

```
_OSAtomicAdd32:
ldxr    w8, [x1]
add     w8, w8, w0
stxr    w9, w8, [x1]
cbnz    w9, _OSAtomicAdd32
mov     x0, x8
ret     lr

_OSAtomicAdd32Barrier:
ldaxr   w8, [x1]
add     w8, w8, w0
stlxr   w9, w8, [x1]
cbnz    w9, _OSAtomicAdd32Barrier
mov     x0, x8
ret     lr
```

In which scenarios would you need the Load-Acquire / Store-Release semantics of the latter? Can `LDXR`/`STXR` instructions be reordered? If they can, is it possible for an atomic update to be "lost" in the absence of a barrier? From what I've read, it doesn't seem like that can happen, and if true, then why would you need the `Barrier` variant? Perhaps only if you also happened to need a `DMB` for other purposes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OSAtomicAdd32Barrier()` exists for people that are using `OSAtomicAdd()` for something beyond just atomic increment.  Specifically, they are implementing their own multi-processing synchronization primitives based on `OSAtomicAdd()`.  For example, creating their own mutex library.  `OSAtomicAdd32Barrier()` uses heavy barrier instructions to enforce memory ordering on both side of the atomic operation.  This is not desirable in normal usage.

To summarize:

1) If you just want to increment an integer in a thread-safe way, use `OSAtomicAdd32()`

2) If you are stuck with a bunch of old code that foolishly assumes `OSAtomicAdd32()` can be used as an interprocessor memory ordering and speculation barrier, replace it with `OSAtomicAdd32Barrier()`

Comment: Thanks! And to generalize point one of your summary to other platforms: "If you just want to increment an integer in a thread-safe way, **use `ldxr`, `add`, `stxr` in a loop until `stxr` succeeds**".

Answer (score 22):

Oh, the mind-bending horror of weak memory ordering...

The first snippet is your basic atomic read-modify-write - if someone else touches whatever address `x1` points to, the store-exclusive will fail and it will try again until it succeeds. So far so good. However, this only applies to the address (or more rightly region) covered by the exclusive monitor, so whilst it's good for *atomicity*, it's ineffective for *synchronisation* of anything other than that value.

Consider a case where CPU1 is waiting for CPU0 to write some data to a buffer. CPU1 sits there waiting on some kind of synchronisation object (let's say a semaphore), waiting for CPU0 to update it to signal that new data is ready.

1. CPU0 writes to the data address.
2. CPU0 increments the semaphore (atomically, as you do) which happens to be elsewhere in memory.
3. ???
4. CPU1 sees the new semaphore value.
5. CPU1 reads *some* data, which may or may not be the old data, the new data, or some mix of the two.

Now, what happened at step 3? Maybe it all occurred in order. Quite possibly, the hardware decided that since there was no address dependency it would let the store to the semaphore go ahead of the store to the data address. Maybe the semaphore store hit in the cache whereas the data didn't. Maybe it just did so because of complicated reasons only those hardware guys understand. Either way it's perfectly possible for CPU1 to see the semaphore update *before* the new data has hit memory, thus read back invalid data.

To fix this, CPU0 must have a barrier between steps 1 and 2, to ensure the data has definitely been written *before* the semaphore is written. Having the atomic write *be* a barrier is a nice simple way to do this. However since barriers are pretty performance-degrading you want the lightweight no-barrier version as well for situations where you don't need this kind of full synchronisation.

Now, the *even less* intuitive part is that CPU1 could also reorder its loads. Again since there is no address dependency, it would be free to speculate the data load before the semaphore load irrespective of CPU0's barrier. Thus CPU1 also needs its own barrier between steps 4 and 5.

For the more authoritative, but pretty heavy going, version have a read of ARM's [Barrier Litmus Tests and Cookbook](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.genc007826/index.html). Be warned, this stuff can be *confusing* ;)

As an aside, in this case the architectural semantics of acquire/release complicate things further. Since they are only one-way barriers, whilst `OSAtomicAdd32Barrier` adds up to a full barrier relative to code before and after it, it doesn't actually guarantee any ordering relative to the atomic operation itself - see [this discussion from Linux](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2014-February/229588.html) for more explanation. Of course, that's from the theoretical point of view of the architecture; in reality it's not inconceivable that the A7 hardware has taken the 'simple' option of wiring up `LDAXR` to just do `DMB+LDXR`, and so on, meaning they can get away with this since they're at liberty to code to their own implementation, rather than the specification.

Comment: Thanks for the well written and detailed answer! I wish I could accept more than one answer. I did read a bit of the Barrier Litmus Test before posting my question, but these answers have really helped clear up my confusions.

Comment: @DaveLee, to be honest, this answered the question: "is it possible for an atomic update to be 'lost' in the absence of a barrier?" whereas the "accepted" answer does not.  In fact, it's better to simply not accept an answer so we can sort answers by votes.  Notlikethat's answer is factually more helpful to more people; it really doesn't make sense for SO to bury it just so some random user gets 10 extra "points," or whatever they hand out these days.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that this is simply a way of reproducing existing architecture-independent semantics for this operation.

With the `ldaxr`/`stlxr` pair, the above sequence will assure correct ordering if the AtomicAdd32 is used as a synchronization mechanism (mutex/semaphore) - regardless of whether the resulting higher-level operation is an acquire or release.

So - this is not about enforcing consistency of the atomic add, but about enforcing ordering between acquiring/releasing a mutex and any operations performed on the resource protected by that mutex.

It is less efficient than the `ldxar`/`stxr` or `ldxr`/`stlxr` you would use in a normal native synchronization mechanism, but if you have existing platform-independent code expecting an atomic add with those semantics, this is probably the best way to implement it.

Comment: Thanks! Saying it's for "reproducing existing architecture-independent semantics" is a very helpful perspective to understand. Much appreciated.