# LLVM Cross Compiling to MIPS on Windows x64

Tags: c, assembly, llvm, mips, llvm-clang

I am trying to compile a very simple Hello World C-program to MIPS assembly on a winx64 machine using llvm/clang.

I have searched for this issue and whilst there are a number of threads with similar topics they almost exclusively use linux and more often than not do not provide any form of solution.

I was under the impression that if I get the latest LLVM binaries and install that on my windows machine I would be able to cross compile say C to MIPS assembly right out of the box.
Is that not the case or am I missing something?

If I target anything besides windows I get an error for the missing header file stdio.h
Isn´t the thing designed to do exactly that? Convert my C code into the given target asm?

Also there seems no Config.h on windows like there is on linux to change certain hardcoded paths.

Maybe I am totally misunderstanding something about llvm/clang.
Hope anyone can help point me in a direction to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: "I get an error for the missing header file stdio.h Isn´t the thing designed to do exactly that? Convert my C code into the given target asm?" - but if you're including stdio.h then you're asking it to do more than that: you're asking it to build against a C runtime library that it can't find. I know GCC better than LLVM but for GCC you'd need to give it header files and libraries from the target system e.g. copy them off a MIPS Linux distribution. (And it would need to have had these to build the compiler in the first place.) But LLVM may be different. Where will you run this binary?

Comment: LLVM can handle many different varieties of crosscompilation, but the binaries aren't built with all that. If you want to crosscompile, you generally have to build from source. (And, as @Rup says, you have provide header files etc. for the target rather than the host system.)

Comment: Thanks for your input, the picture is clearer now. I am not trying to build a binary, just the mips assembly to run it on a simulated mips processor. I will look for the header files from MIPS and try to pass them as the include dir.

Comment: clang on Godbolt works for many random architectures, like `-target sparc64` or `-target mips`, like in the Godbolt link in my answer on [What exact rules in the C++ memory model prevent reordering before acquire operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636008).  https://godbolt.org/z/zT2rkp.  Sometimes you run into problems with headers, but for some stuff it works great if you just want to see how compilers do something on MIPS or whatever other ISA.

Answer (score 0):

https://sites.google.com/site/lccretargetablecompiler/

https://github.com/drh/lcc

LCC a retargetable C compiler ran under windows and could output x86, Mips R3000, SPARC, or ALPHA processors.

Check it out to produce your mips assembly code.

Or look at clang/llvm compiler
https://llvm.org/docs/HowToCrossCompileLLVM.html