# Consequences of "atomic object" interpretation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, atomic, stdatomic

There is a thread discussing [the definition of atomic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885590/definition-of-atomic-object). The most popular interpretations are the followings:

- By an "atomic object" we understand an object whose public interface exposes only atomic operations, i.e. all operations you can do with that object are atomic.
- The C++ has the standard `std::atomic<T>` class template which fits the above descriptions.
- The C++ standard imposes a set of rules on operations and effects of operations on atomic objects ([[intro.races]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races)). If all operations on an object satisfy those rules, then that object is atomic.

I see two possible interpretations for the atomic object:

- An `std::atomic<T>` typed object
- An underlying `T` typed object managed by an `std::atomic<T>` typed object

Based on the comments and in my understanding "atomic object" should refer an object with `std::atomic<T>` type - so the first interpretation is the correct one -, but it has serious consequences, like in the following context:

*C++20 standard 6.9.2.1 (15):*

> If an operation `A` that modifies an atomic object `M` happens before an operation `B` that modifies `M`, then `A` shall be earlier than `B` in the modification order of `M`.

There is an `std::atomic` operation with the following footprint:

```
void notify_one() noexcept;
```

As it is not a `const` function it modifies the `std::atomic` object, but it doesn't modify the underlying `T` object. Does `notify_one` modify the atomic object `M`? (Does `M` refer the `std::atomic<T>` typed object, or its underlying `T` object?). If it does refer the `std::atomic` typed object then *C++20 standard 6.9.2.1 (15)* can be applied for the `notify_one` operations.

It is crucial to know to be able to answer questions like [C++20: How is the returning from atomic::wait() guaranteed by the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228390/c20-how-is-the-returning-from-atomicwait-guaranteed-by-the-standard).

The standard is confusing however, e.g. here, it weakens my reasoning and says atomic object is the managed object (at least in the case of `atomic_ref`):

> An `atomic_­ref` object applies atomic operations ([[atomics.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.general)) to the object referenced by `*ptr` such that, for the lifetime ([[basic.life]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life)) of the `atomic_­ref` object, the object referenced by `*ptr` is an atomic object ([[intro.races]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races)).

**UPDATE**

How could this interpretation affect `wait/notify` ([C++20: How is the returning from atomic::wait() guaranteed by the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228390/c20-how-is-the-returning-from-atomicwait-guaranteed-by-the-standard))? Let's suppose `notify` modifies the atomic object. That modification would be simply an indication that a `wait` should be woken up - and nothing to do with the current value managed by the `atomic` (so basically a futex wake that modifies the object, stores a flag, or whatever). As both `store` and `notify` are operations

> that modifies an atomic object `M`, then `A` shall be earlier than `B` in the modification order of `M`

and

> this effectively makes the cache coherence guarantee provided by most hardware available to C++ atomic operations.

So whenever `notify` is called after a `store`, the effect of that `store` operation is guaranteed to be observable on each and every waiting thread when that thread observes `notify` (as `notify` is later than `store` in the total order). If there is a waiting operation "`M` is eligible to be unblocked by a call to an atomic notifying operation" then `notify` must unblock it, and the value set by `store` has to be observable by the unblocked `wait` as an implication of 6.9.2.1 (15):

> If an operation `A` that modifies an atomic object `M` happens before an operation `B` that modifies `M`, then `A` shall be earlier than `B` in the modification order of `M`.

and 6.9.2.1 (4):

> All modifications to a particular atomic object `M` occur in some
> particular total order, called the modification order of `M`.

Comment: The issue has already been raised [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/96). Also note that as said there, it only really makes sense for the modification order to apply to the managed object or its scalar subobjects regardless. I think it may be true that there should be a statement about data race avoidance for the non-`const` wait/notify functions. I am surprised that they are non-`const` to begin with. According to the commit message at the end of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102994 nobody really seems to have cared either way.

Comment: @user17732522 Great to see! "Also note that as said there, it only really makes sense for the modification order to apply to the managed object regardless" - I disagree here. If the `notify_` operations would be part of the modification order related restrictions then the `wait/notify` synchronization would be solved automatically (as forcing the `store` operation before the `notify` would eliminate the need to synchronize the `wait` with `notify`, as the `store` and `notify` observation order would be the same on the waiting thread).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer good question. The standard gives us a function footprint and a description what a function should do. It doesn't say explicitly that `notify` must modify the object, but it explicitly gives the permission to modify the object by marking the function non-const. `const` functions must not modify the object, but we don't have any modifier that forces the implementation to modify the object. The standard doesn't specify the exact algorithm, so -without knowing the exact implementation- it is the best indication I can figure out. If you have a better idea please share it.

Comment: For `std::atomic<T>`, unlike `atomic_ref`, there doesn't seem to be any indication that there even has to exist an "underlying" object of type `T`.  We could imagine implementing `std::atomic<char>` with a `long int` under the hood, and load and store doing appropriate conversions, or some deeper magic that doesn't map to C++ at all, with no object of type `char` anywhere in the picture.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see your point, but what could be a better indication of possible modifications than marking the function non-const? Does `std::random_device::operator()` e.g. modify the object, or it just adjusts a global variable? It is up to the implementation I think, but as it is not a `const` function it could modify the object. The only hint the standard can give to us is whether the function is marked `const` or not. What does 'modify' mean in your interpretation?

Comment: I do agree that `.notify()` *could* modify the object.  But that alone does not resolve the wait/notify question from the other thread.  In order to use modification order to prove that the wait will return, we would need to use read-read coherence, which requires that the `notify()` actually *does* modify the object, that it stores a value which was equal to the previous value in the modification order, that the unblock in the `wait()` is a value computation, and that it takes its value from the `notify()`.  And I don't find support in the standard for any of those statements.

Comment: @NateEldredge please see the update. I think you misunderstood how I think this interpretation could affect the `wait/notify` issue, I tried to be as detailed in my explanation as possible.

Comment: @NateEldredge _read-read coherence, which requires that the `notify()` actually does modify the object_ Does it require? _the unblock in the `wait()` is a value computation, and that it takes its value from the `notify()`_ The unblock can take the value from the last Y before the `notify()` (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/atomics.wait#4.3)

Comment: Prolly it will have to say «as if it takes the value», since, AFAIK, `volatile` bullshit still exists