# Atomic 64 bit counter on ARM 32 bit MCU without locks

Tags: c, concurrency, embedded, atomic, race-condition

On a ARM Cortex M 32 bit, under C, I need to maintain a 64 bit counter.  I want to avoid a race condition like:

```
start:
         count = 0x00000000 ffffffff
threadA: increment count_low
         count = 0x00000000 00000000
threadB: increment count_low
         count = 0x00000000 00000001
threadA: if (!count_low) increment count_high
         count = 0x00000000 00000001
threadB: if (!count_low) increment count_high
         count = 0x00000000 00000001
```

It's a simple counter which will be used only two ways: 1. Read val and 2. Increment.

In ARM assembly, this can be done without introducing any locks, via `LDREX` and `STREX`.  However, I'd like to avoid assembly and use C.

Is the best way to do this simply to use `atomic_uint_least64_t` ? Will that work?

When I try making my counter `atomic_uint_least64_t` , I get linker errors `undefined reference to`__atomic_load_8'`, and when I try adding` -latomic`, I get` cannot find "-latomic:" No such file or directory`.

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` on Linux to cross compile for Cortex M.

Comment: Do you get the same (or similar) errors while working with 32-bit atomic variables? Is this on Cortex M0 or something else (like M3 or M4)?

Comment: There is no libatomic implementation for those targets (at least I am not aware of). So you need to provide your own mechanisms. I afraid the only wat is to use RTOS critical sections. Not perfect but it works

Comment: If you had only a single writer thread, a SeqLock can be a good pattern.  (Or if you compile with an  ARM32 `-mcpu=` that supports 64-bit atomic pure-load and pure-store, you can just use `atomic_uint_least64_t` with relaxed load and relaxed store.)  Since you do need multiple writers, use `fetch_add`; hopefully you're compiling for a target with `ldrexd` / `strexd` (double-register) so it can inline that lock-free code instead of emitting a call to a libatomic helper function.  e.g. `-mcpu=cortex-a15` but not `m4`. https://godbolt.org/z/KPonqdWYM

Comment: It seems there aren't any Cortex-M CPUs that support ldrexd / strexd.  https://reviews.llvm.org/D95891 .  So you'd need a libatomic implementation that disables interrupts, I guess, or something non-lock-free that has a separate spinlock or that uses a bit of the counter to claim it as modification in progress.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unfortunatelly libatomic was not implemented for those targets (at least not in mainstream toolchains)

Comment: @PeterCordes what is the point of posting examples for Cortex-a if the question is about Cortex-M?

Comment: @0___________ I only noticed the Cortex-M part of the question after having written that comment, so just made a small edit.  And wasn't sure at first that *no* Cortex-M CPUs supported 64-bit atomicity, I thought maybe some of the higher-end Cortex-M CPUs might.  Also, SeqLock is worth mentioning for future readers that only have one writer thread; that is easily implementable with purely 32-bit loads/stores.

Comment: The real question to ask here is why you are attempting to use threads on a Cortex M? If the program is complex enough to motivate the use of something like that, you should be using RTOS processes not threads. And then use the mechanism the RTOS provides for race condition protection.

Comment: @Lundin I'm writing a lightweight RTOS for personal use.  _Not_ to replace a production RTOS for production.  But to learn.  It's quite functional already with a very small codebase.

Comment: @SRobertJames Then you've probably already figured out how to do the very same thing during context switches? The way I usually do it is to have all tasks scheduled by a dedicated hardware timer/rtc with cyclic interrupts, context switching is carried out from inside the non-interruptable ISR. And then you can implement critical sections by disabling said timer interrupt - which won't affect real-time unless you do it close to the time when the cyclic interrupt is about to trigger. Depending on how picky your real-time spec is, that might be fine still.

Comment: As for learning, just have a peek at some RTOS source for the same target and see how they do it there?

Answer (score -1):

Just use `stdatomic.h` primitives.

They will *do the right thing* for whatever arch.

And, the code will be inlined [where possible].

For arm, they might use `ldrex`. And they might use `dmb` for a memory barrier. But, they might also use `ldaxr`.

**Edit:** Or, they might do something else (see the update section below).

---

Here's a sample program:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

unsigned long long ctr;

void
ctrinc(void)
{

    atomic_fetch_add(&ctr,1);
}
```

Here's the assembly:

```
    .arch armv8-a
    .file   "atom64.c"
    .text
    .comm   ctr,8,8
    .align  2
    .global ctrinc
    .type   ctrinc, %function
ctrinc:
    adrp    x0, :got:ctr
    ldr x0, [x0, #:got_lo12:ctr]
.L2:
    ldaxr   x1, [x0]
    add x1, x1, 1
    stlxr   w2, x1, [x0]
    cbnz    w2, .L2
    nop
    ret
    .size   ctrinc, .-ctrinc
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

---

Some resources:

1. [ARM64: LDXR/STXR vs LDAXR/STLXR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21535058/5382650)
2. [What's the difference between LDAXR and LDREX](https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/architectures-and-processors-forum/9482/what-s-the-difference-between-ldaxr-and-ldrex)

---

**UPDATE:**

> Op asked about 32bit cortex-m (thumb) not ARM-64 –
> 0___________

Yes, I had easy access to `aarch64` cross compiler. But at the top I did say: "*whatever* arch". OP can just cross-compile with the correct `-m*` options.

The use of the `atomic_fetch_add` was fine. The compiler will do *whatever is necessary* to implement the primitive.

The fact that I only was able to provide the 64 bit asm output does *not* invalidate the basic premise: Use `stdatomic.h` primitives.

> LDREX STREX are not 100% atomic as they are restarted if interrupt arrives –
> 0___________

Yes, no worries ...

That is why the functions loop conditionally to retry. This is well known by the [compiler] designers for `atomic_*` for arm processors.

*Side note:*

1. Also, we can't [successfully] do instruction single step [under `gdb`'s `si`] because of the way it must be implemented.
2. This is a quirk/restriction of `arm`. We *can* do `si` on such sequences in `x86` (e.g.) because `addx/addq` and `cmpxchg*` are single instructions).
3. But, while `addq` et. al. is 100% atomic, even in x86, we loop on the `cmpxchg*`
4. But `arm` will *always* fail because any interruption between `ldrex` and `strex` [they are paired] will release the lock (including the `si` command).

> Any cortex-m is not 64 bits as in your answer. Your answer does not answer anything –
> 0___________

Yes, it *does*. I reiterate: *They will **do the right thing** for whatever arch.*

If this means that the implementation calls a library function (from `libgcc`) that uses a *thin* hidden spinlock, then they are doing the fastest/most efficient implementation possible on a given arch.

IIRC, even Herb Sutter [who did the research leading up to the `stdatomic.h` or C++ equivalent standards] when people complained about [the compiler] using a spinlock mentioned that doing such a spinlock was fine. This was particularly true for adding an `_Atomic` attribute to an entire `struct`. This was *not* always a single global spinlock, but [where possible] was a different spinlock/mutex for each instance. I think these talks (circa 2004) are available (on youtube?) [but I'm too exhausted from the sturm-und-drang here to look for the link for what I watched].

This *is* what Peter found on his godbolt link:

```
bl      __atomic_fetch_add_8
```

So be it ... Lockless is somewhat overrated (and even some of its proponents say so). Sometimes the lockless code is *less* performant than using a spinlock/mutex.

One *should* use the `stdatomic.h` primitives because the *compiler* will pick the best implementation.

For arm:

1. It will use `ldaxr/staxr` if the arch supports it.
2. `ldrex/strex` if the arch supports it. For some arches, after this pair, we'll see a `dmb ish` or equiv.
3. A function [or inline code] that uses `ldrex/strex` on a separate spinlock if needed (i.e. the arch is 32 bit only but the compiler will transparently generate whatever code is required).

It's the simple solution because it's the compiler's *job* to *know* which implementation is the best.

Here, responders often say that the compiler will usually generate *better* code than some [naive] hand written asm optimization. For example:

1. It will optimize a simple loop with appropriate SIMD instructions. You could code this by hand for (e.g. `x86`) but that would have to be redone for `arm`. Or s/390, or `mips`, or `risc-v` ...
2. For support of `uint64_t` integer addition, on `x86_64`, it will use real 64 bit `addq` instructions. For `i386`, it will use `add` followed by `adc`

This rule applies to atomics as well. In most cases, the compiler will generate better code than trying to figure it out by hand. Even if that means using a spinlock/mutex.

Comment: Op asked about 32bit cortex-m (thumb) not ARM-64

Comment: I have UV it by mistake and not my vote is locked

Comment: LDREX STREX are not 100% atomic as they are restarted if interrupt arrives

Comment: Yes, this won't work for ARM 32 bit Cortex.

Comment: @SRobertJames Which Cortex? M3, M0, etc. What `-march=` and `-mtune=` options, etc. are you using. As I said, "_whatever_" arch Did you compile the sample in your environment? What did you get? Maybe you should edit your question and post the asm.

Comment: Any cortex-m is not 64 bits as in your answer. Your answer does not answer anything

Comment: @CraigEstey: All Cortex-M CPUs/MCUs are 32-bit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M).  And it seems none of them even support ldrexd / strexd for lock-free `_Atomic uint64_t`, unfortunately.  At least not in 2021 when https://reviews.llvm.org/D95891 was posted.  So they'd need a `libatomic` implementation that disabled interrupts, for single-core machines.  (IIRC, there are some multi-core cortex-M.)  Even Armv8.1-M (like Cortex-M85) still only uses a subset of T32 (AArch32 state Thumb encodings), not including `ldrexd`. https://godbolt.org/z/d88vKx8os

Comment: @PeterCordes there more important things in uC design than atomic access to the large objects. Every transistor consumes energy and with the correct software design, it is simply not needed.

Comment: @0___________ I've updated my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've updated my answer. From the mentioned Herb Sutter talk, IIRC, he said that (if necessary), the primitives for "large" objects with `_Atomic` attributes _are_ implemented using [lite] spinlocks

Comment: In an embedded system where some of the accesses might be from interrupt handlers, being non-lock-free is a huge deal.  If an interrupt handler runs on the same core as code that holds the lock, a spinlock deadlocks.  If `__atomic_fetch_add_8` is implemented by disabling interrupts on a single-core system, you don't have that problem, but that doesn't work for multi-core.  (And that does raise interrupt latency slightly, if real-time worst-case is a concern.)

Comment: Also, your answer has the wrong instruction names in the ARM32 section.  The relevant ARMv7 instructions are `ldrexd` / `strexd` (double-register, not available on Cortex-M).  `ldaxr` / `stlxr` (exclusive with acquire/release and seq_cst semantics) are an AArch64 thing. (https://godbolt.org/z/168axa7rP ).The ARMv8 32-bit-mode instructions are `ldaexd` and `stlexd`.  Cortex-M55/85 support the 32-bit single-register versions of these, `ldaex`/`stlex`, but that's still no help here.

Comment: The other difficulty with non-lock-free atomics is that **the OP's `arm-none-eabi-gcc` toolchain doesn't come with a `libatomic`**.  They say in the question compiling with `gcc ... -latomic` says the library wasn't found at link time.  IDK if an implementation of `libatomic.a` for single-core Cortex-M systems is available anywhere, but that would be an essential part of an answer claiming that it will Just Work.

Comment: @CraigEstey did you try to compiler and **link** it? Yur answer still does not answer anything as there is no official libatomic implementation for cortex-M target. Your answer is simply useless. \