# How can we use multi core and cpu on Assembly boot loader x86

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader

i was reading making your new OS docs as shown here:
http://joelgompert.com/OS/TableOfContents.htm

These examples shows how to make boot loader for x86.
But i don't know how to make it concurrent ?
Is there any documents that explains how to run all cores ?
How can i activate all of the cores and run asm separate each of them.

Is there any documents for ARM CPUs also ?
Or can someone explain here in detail ?

Comment: Minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33651438/895245

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the same for all CPU types (that's even just within x86, it is of course even more radically different on different architectures).

Ignoring ancient hardware, a rough sketch of the procedure on x86:

- prepare the system for the start of other cpus (only 1 core is active at first) (parse MP table, init APIC, do some stuff you need)
- send a SIPI
- wait for it
- send a second SIPI (maybe, not sure how necessary it is)
- wait for it
- let the other APs increment a counter so you know how many woke up
- wait until as many APs started as you expected (based on the number of cores found in the MP table)

See Intel System Programming Guide chapter 8 (multiple-processor management) for a more thorough and correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from "ALLAN CRUSE" that shows how to startup x86 cores: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs630/mphello.s