# How does multi-core CPU work and how does the multiple cores commuicate?

Tags: cpu, computer-science, virtualization

As i write my virtual machine, i have come up across many problems but this has been the most annoying one. When i think about implementing multiple virtual cores, i have encountered following problems:
How do multiple cores communicate?
I found that it is a nightmare to figure out how core-core communication plays out. I thought about making one core a Master CPU that could run a small virtual OS which will assign and manage the other cores(which is called Master-Slave technique apparently[I came up with it on my own]).

How does the OS that mostly runs on one core make the other cores work?
How does the cores communicate with each other, interrupt each other?
If the OS assigns a thread to a different core, How does it let the executing core know how much to execute?

Knowing the answer to these is all i want. Other problems are solvable.

As for my try to the first question, here is what i came up with next apart from the Master-slave one.
The memory is divided into 4 fixed blocks. The first block is for the virtual firmware. The other three blocks are for individual virtual cores to read from. Initially all the cores except the master, are idle. When the Master core encountered a request for multi-threading, it would look for a free core, move the block that needed to be executed to that core's memory block and send a signal to it start working. After finishing or encountering an error, the working slave core would send a signal to the Master core and the signal would be handled. But this approach has its own difficulties and problems.

Comment: Not sure what goal you have in mind with your VM. If you're after a basic understanding of modern CPUs, a better first approximation is to think of cores as sharing nothing except the same memory bus. Core synchronization then boils down to how that memory bus resolves conflicting access. (E.g. compare-and-swap instruction.)

Comment: Related (for x86): [What does multicore assembly language look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/980999).  Once the other cores boot the kernel, they're equal partners.  e.g. the scheduler is normally a distributed algorithm that atomically claims a runnable task from the queue, not master/slave.  There's shared memory and IPIs (Inter-Processor Interrupts).