# What does good, modern c code look like?

Tags: c

I'm primarily a c#/.NET programmer, but the [hobby project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180/how-to-get-started-in-operating-system-development) that I am about to take on will involve coding in c.

I know that there is a ton of c code out there, but its very hard to separate a well structured c project from a badly structured project if you did not "grow up" with the language.  Can anyone point me toward a newer, non trivial (but not enormous) project that is considered a good example of how to structure c code?

**Edit**

If you cannot find a project, feel free to discuss in words how you think a c project should be structured.

Comment: https://ziglang.org/, not Rust not D not Go not Jai not C++ not Ada not Pascal no Modula not ATS not BitC not What else?

Comment: not Nim nor Fortran

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/) is a *very* well-crafted library of about 7000 lines of code.  The book is great if you can afford it.

The implementation of the [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) programming language and libraries is about 17,000 lines of C code and is very well done but quite sophisticated in places—compilers and garbage collectors are not so easy to understand without background in those fields.  But the code is beautifully engineered.

Git is over 125,000 lines of code.  I can't recommend that anyone study it as an example of how to engineer C code.  Just the design and public interfaces, let alone the implementations, are hard to understand—which is why there are so many git tutorials.

Comment: +1 for Lua. I was pleasantly surprised when I took a look under the hood to see if it was going to be acceptable performance and quality wise for an embedded software project I was on.

Comment: Git has consistent style and structure so it is good material to learn. You don't have to ready every line of it!

Comment: @Norman looks like the book is available on Safari.  I must have skipped it over because it is 13 years old (assumed it wouldn't be "modern code"), but I'll check it out on your recommendation; thanks!

Comment: 125,000 lines of GIT versus 17,000 lines of Lua doesn't make much diference in this case, since he will not (probably) read every line...

Comment: @git advocates: How will the OP know where to get started?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Check out git source code: http://github.com/git/git/tree/master

Comment: 125,000 lines of code for a new C programmer?  Are you sure?

Comment: It is all about the structure and the style. You don't have to read every line though.

Answer (score 6):

I consider Steve Dekorte's [IO language](http://iolanguage.com/) implementation to be a good example for clean and pragmatic modern-day C.

Comment: I agree, it's really nice code. I like it and I can understand it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is completely anecdotal, but I've heard that the [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) project is considered good code.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

"The C Programming Language", 2nd edition, Kernighan and Ritchie

Answers to Exercises

http://users.powernet.co.uk/eton/kandr2/

Answer (score 1):

The following book (with code examples) could ease your paradigm shift a bit:

Stephen Kochan

Programming in C, Third Edition

http://www.kochan-wood.com

Answer (score 1):

[image: C: A reference Manual By Harbison and Steele]

[C: A Reference Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X) contains a variety of example code usage, with implementations centric to Standard C; A definite document to look into, perhaps along with the C Std.

Answer (score 1):

The SVN project is written entirely in C and it is well maintained: consistently styled, good comments, low code smell.  I recommend [perusing](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#source-release) it.