# Dreaming of making my own OS- what should I use? (suggestions)

Tags: linux, operating-system

I was just wanting to go ahead and make an OS. Because working on projects makes one's knowledge quite good enough. I know I will have to study OS inside-out before actually trying to implement one on my own. I also know I wouldn't be able to implement something right from square one. So I searched the internet for something to work upon. The most common option that I found was to work upon existing Linux distro and contribute to it.
But I found some more interesting options. Would like your suggestions on what to choose for and work upon.

LFS: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/

PintOS: http://www.scs.stanford.edu/10wi-cs140/pintos/pintos_1.html#SEC1

Cosmos: http://www.gocosmos.org/index.en.aspx

I would get around 6 months time to work upon it. But before I start off with it, I want to do my research work properly and finalize what and how to work.
Drop in your suggestions on what should I use to work on. :)

Comment: See [How to get started in operating system development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180/how-to-get-started-in-operating-system-development)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I was really starting to get discouraged considering all the down votes. And I found LFS in your list too!

Comment: THis is an excellent question that does not deserve to be downvoted or closed. You will learn a whole lot by doing this project, and I think six months in not too unrealistic a schedule. If I were doing it, I'd pick the LFS framework: you will gain knowledge that is widely useful. The reason for undertaking this project? One of your links had the answer: "Because it's fun!" Good for you and good luck!

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara -- downvotes happen for many different reasons, sometimes arising from voters' internal feelings about themselves (as I claim). They do not necessarily reflect the worth of the question. In your case, you asked a very good question, one that only a tiny minority of programmers have the vision and curiosity to conceive. To the other blinkered slaggards, we say 'feh! ptui!' and we move on to ever-brightening heights, leaving them behind to struggle in our dust. Yes we do.

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara -- I'm going to do the same thing because of your encouragement and following your lead. So THANKS! for the idea and especially thanks for mentioning LFS, which I hadn't heard of. (Yeah, and I'm gonna' read "War and Peace", too :-)