# Operating System in Java

Tags: linux, mobile, operating-system, kernel

We a team of 10 people are set out to build an Operating System for mobiles/tablet from scratch.

I then came by this link [awesome-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180/what-are-some-resources-for-getting-started-in-operating-system-development)
which has a load of OS briefed. But we would like to build the OS in Java on top of linux kernel(possible?) .

I would like to know whether the project is feasible and if yes, from where should I start ? 
And with all the knowledge and right resources(assume), will it be possible to build an OS with all the mobile functionalities within 6 months?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is beyond broad: it's a wide-load, OP. A good explanation and/or discussion will take too long. Try breaking your question down a little more.

Answer (score 1):

> But we would like to build the OS in Java on top of linux kernel(possible?)

Yes, what do you think Android is made of (of course it's not just Java + Linux kernel, but both are inside Android)?

> I would like to know whether the project is feasible and if yes, from where should I start ?

Ever written an OS? How well do you know Linux kernel APIs? Do you know what's missing from Linux kernel to build a full featured OS? Answer those, they're your starting point.

> And with all the knowledge and right resources(assume), will it be possible to build an OS with all the mobile functionalities within 6 months?

"All mobile functionalities" is biased, what is "all"? Be specific.

Comment: Thanks Lele! Ya I know Android is build on kernel. But the core is written in C/C++ if I'm right. BTW we opted out Android as we wanted to make something unique.

Comment: "I know Android is build on kernel" <-- ???
Android uses Linux kernel which is written in C (no C++ AFAIK). I don't suggest you to take Android route, just to show you something that's written in Java on top of Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Please make enough research and planning before you are set out to start such a difficult, yet excellent journey.

Make sure you know what you should do, right from the technologies you are gonna use, the architecture you are planning to establish upon, the pros and cons of all the approach, the issues with the current OS and your idea of correcting those issues.

With a site like SO for your help, it is never a question of feasibility, but you would require the determination and the perseverance to achieve it.

Finally, all the best!!

Answer (score 1):

You have Android build on scaled down Linux Kernel and apk is build through java & sdk manager. So you have the things in your hand, similarly ubuntu touch is also coming. What you can do is to customize things as per your requirements as per your architecture.

For ubuntu touch :-  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Building
For Your own customized Android:-  http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker