# How to create new os?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I want to develop new operating system so I want to know about what are the areas I have to study. Also the select language to code this OS. Could you provide any special areas I have to follow before starting this project.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not suited for **recommendation** questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some resources for getting started in operating system development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180/what-are-some-resources-for-getting-started-in-operating-system-development)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to research that on Internet, there are many articles.
https://medium.com/@abeysinghechamath/writing-your-own-operating-system-2e0909938249